# How do I export a function correctly in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I try to invoke my serverless function I get `Type Error login is not a function`, I believe there is something I am not doing correctly when exporting my function,

I am trying to arrange my project so I can import all of the functions in the `utils/` folder easily
I have a directory structure like this:

```
handler.js
utils/
  login.js
  index.js
```

handler.js file

```
"use strict";
const {login} = require("./utils");

const username = 'user';
const password = 'pass';

module.exports.scrape = (event, context, callback) => {
  login(username, password)
      .catch(error =>
      callback(new Error(`Error scraping ${event}: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`))
    );
};
```

index.js file

```
module.exports = {
    login: require("./login"),
  };
```

login.js file

```
async function login(username, password) {
    // my function does something
};

module.exports.login = login;
```

Comment: Try `const { login: { login } } = require("./utils");`, maybe that illustrates the issue.

Comment: use only export `exports.login = login`;

Comment: `module.exports = require("./login")` also works

Answer (score -1):

In handler.js file, get login object while requiring utils

> const login = require("./utils").login;